# How can I get my Pi to show nothing but a black screen until it loads LXDE?

Tags: raspbian

I know this is a bizarre question, but I need the Pi to display images to serve as a digital sign. The reason I want a black screen through the whole boot process is just so I don't have all that kernel text whizzing by.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the splash through a `config.txt` entry, but at this time there is no way to prevent the kernel output from displaying without recompiling the kernel.

From the official [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md)

> ### DISABLE_SPLASH
>
> If set to 1, don't show the rainbow splash screen on boot. The default value is 0.